# Put a variable in a .SelectSingleNode expression

Tags: c#, xml, selectsinglenode

I want to write a method which replaces an attribute at a certain node in a XML-File. Here is my code. The [Node] should be my variable to select the correct node I want. For example "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..."

This is my XML, I want to choose for example the second  "Guid"

```
<Tools>
    <Tools> 
        <Tool>
           <ID>xxx</ID>
        </Tool>
        <Tool>
           <ID>xxx</ID>
        </Tool>
    </Tools>
 </Tools>

public void replace (int Node) {
XmlNode Set = xmldoc2.DocumentElement;
string strXmlQuery = "/Tools/Tools/Tool[Node]/ID";
XmlNode NodeToChange = Set.SelectSingleNode(strXmlQuery);
```

Comment: Guid is an element, not an attribute.

Comment: `strXmlQuery` contains `ID` but your XML contains `Guid`?

Comment: I think its not important if "ID" is an element or an attribute? I only want to choose the second "ID" with a variable. 
If i replace the path [Node] with [2], it works. But I want to have the expression [...] with a variable, so that its flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to replace `Node` in query text by variable:

```
int id = 2;
string strXmlQuery = $"/Tools/Tools/Tool[{id}]/ID";
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work.
There´s an exception "'/Tools/Tools/Tool[{id}]/ID" is an invalid token

Comment: My example uses [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) that is available from C# 6.0. It is simplification for `string.format("/Tools/Tools/Tool[{0}]/ID", id);`